# Отличие vim-gnome от vim-nox

Tags: vim

В чем отличие vim-gnome от vim-nox?

Answer (score 1):

судя по именам пакетов, речь о дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* (или о каком-либо его «наследнике»).

значит, смотрим описания (дополненные моим вольным переводом):

1. [vim-gnome](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/vim-gnome):

   > This is a transitional package to install the vim-gtk3 package. You may remove this package if nothing depends on it.
   >
   > это промежуточный пакет для установки пакета vim-gtk3. вы можете удалить этот пакет если ничего не зависит от него.
2. [vim-gtk3](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/vim-gtk3):

   > This package contains a version of vim compiled with a GTK3 GUI and support for scripting with Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby, and Tcl.
   >
   > этот пакет содержит версию программы vim, скомпилированной с GTK3 GUI и поддержкой скриптинга на Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby и Tcl.
3. [vim-nox](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/vim-nox):

   > This package contains a version of vim compiled with support for scripting with Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby, and Tcl but no GUI.
   >
   > этот пакет содержит версию программы vim, скомпилированной с поддержкой скриптинга на Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby и Tcl, но без GUI.

**резюме**: *vim-gnome* — пакет вообще виртуальный, а зависящий от него *vim-gtk3* отличается от *vim-nox* лишь поддержкой GUI.